# Start a specific thread once with an application which can be executed more than one

Tags: c#

I'm trying to start a specific task on a new thread, but I want to start it once only and allow the same application to be executed many times more but without start such task (again).

So far I tried that:

```
class Program {
private static EventWaitHandle s_event;

[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args) {

    bool canCreateTask = false;
    try {
        s_event = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "My Application", out canCreateTask);
    } catch(Exception exception) {
        Console.Write(exception.Message);
    }
    if (canCreateTask) {
        //Create the specific task on a new thread
    }    
}
```

This works fine with the next scenario: I start the application for the first time and the task is started as expected, if I start the application another time (without close the first one), the task doesn't start which is fine too.

The problem comes when I close the first application (with the second one running) and I start a new one again, the task is not started as I would like.

I'm not sure at all if I can achieve that with EventWaitHandle or If I'm doing something wrong.

How i could achieve that?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the `task` has completed? Closing the main `thread` does not kill the `new thread`- to my knowledge

Comment: @Symon: If a thread is marked as a _background_ thread, it will not keep the process alive (it will die when the main thread(s) die).  If it is not a background thread, it will continue running and keep the process alive.

Comment: Symon, @Flydog57, thanks for your answers, but set the thread as a background thread don't seems to solve my problem, it works at the same way I said on the first post. There is anything else I could try?

Comment: That wasn't an answer, that was a comment.  It won't fix your issue.  What you need is a more sophisticated mechanism for maintaining cross-process state.  It's not something I know off the top of my head, so I'm hoping someone else will chime in with an answer.  What you need is something that will remain in some kind of "set" state no matter how many processes have started and stopped.  The first process should start up and set it to "OK", and the last one to close should flip the "OK" off.  It's likely something like a semaphore

Comment: Only let the program that creates the named system synchronization event EventWaitHandle (and thus runs the task/thread) hold onto it until the program ends. Any further program execution that acquires an existing EventWaitHandle (i.e., where the `out bool` parameter becomes _false_) should immediately dispose this EventWaitHandle after checking _canCreateTask_. Otherwise the EventWaitHandle instances of those secondary program executions will hold onto the underlying system synchronization event and keep it alive even if your first program execution (that is/was running the task/thread) ends.

Comment: Thanks @elgonzo, now it works as I expected!